# when don't I give the argument to option, option is not working

Tags: getopts

example code:

```
function purge() {
delete_dir;

   case $purge_arg in
       --static)
       delete_static_dir;
       ;;
   esac

}

while getopts ":nrp:h" opt; do
  case ${opt} in
    h ) guide;
      ;;
    n ) new_address;
      ;;
    r ) tor_server;
      ;;
    p )
      purge_arg=${OPTARG}
      purge
      ;;
  esac
done
```

problem:

```
./script.sh -p --static #it's work
deleting dir;
deleting static dir.



./script.sh -p  #It should run the delete dir command but it doesn't work
```

what should i do to make it run?

Comment: One problem: you call `purge` before setting `purge_arg` (on which `purge` depends)

Comment: sorry, it still doesn't work. Could it be because of the ":" operator's forced argument?

Comment: You can't both require that `-p` takes an argument and allow `-p` to not take an argument, if you use `getopts`.